# Cherokee & .HTAccess files

Tags: web-server, .htaccess, cherokee

I believe that Cherokee does not support .htaccess files (which could be though of as a good thing in terms of speed).

But, how do I do the things I used to do with .htaccess with Cherokee?
Also, some of my clients host their sites on my webserver. How can they utilise .htaccess stuff now that I plan on using Cherokee?

Answer (score 1):

From the Cherokee FAQ (bottom - http://www.cherokee-project.com/doc/other_faq.html):

> I’m used to Apache’s .htaccess. Will Cherokee ever support it?
>   Short answer: No.

But you can try things in Cherokee with "Handlers": http://www.cherokee-project.com/doc/modules_handlers.html

Comment: I get this bit. But the problem is more about how to allow other users of my server to do things they would normally do with .htaccess

Comment: Please describe "do things". And take note of the fact that for a lot of these "things" your clients will need admin-rights in the Cherokee web-interface.